# try to install ruby on rails on my mac, but after evertime i get an error that there is no file or directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, installation, mamp

Homebrew is already installed.
xCode is already installed too.
in use the codecademy youtube tutorial but it doesn't work :(
youtube.com/watch?v=3Lp5XP8pWkU&t=198s

i have installed rvm and i guess this will working but when i want to install ruby it looks that it works but then wenn i type **$ ruby -v** 
i see only this message **-bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ruby: No such file or directory**. i have deleted MAMP from my Mac, but this should also work without Mamp. Or am i wrong i need your help. This message is shown although when i type **rails -v** or **rails new *testApp***. I cant make a new ruby on rails app. i need your help. Please take a look on the images.

[Terminal Code rvm Ruby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyY6N.png)

[Terminal Code error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ0MU.jpg)

Comment: you need to `use` the installed ruby version. what does it say when you do `rvm list`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either your MAMP installation is broken, or MAMP itself is broken.
Can you reinstall MAMP, To "uninstall" MAMP, you only have to delete the MAMP directory and everything returns to the original state (MAMP does not alter anything on the "normal" OS X).

and then try to install ruby

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

Also check your `/.profile` file that it has all the following entries

```
alias erb='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/erb'
alias gem='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/gem'
alias irb='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/irb'
alias rake='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rake'
alias rdoc='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rdoc'
alias ri='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ri'
alias ruby='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ruby'
alias rails='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rails'
```

you can also use `rbenv` if `rvm` is not working for you, here is the tutorial which explains `How to use MAMP with the mysql2 gem and Ruby 1.9.3-p194 via rbenv`

https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/3429066